# Android Application vs Activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have written a few Android apps, and have always declared a starting `Activity` as the:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

It would be great for scoping some global methods, statics, shared prefs, etc if I could start my app using an `Application` that then calls the first `Activity` from it's `onCreate()` after setting up prefs, etc, but I haven't been able to find any examples of this design pattern... when I try this in code, I get a `ClassCastException`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // do stuff (prefs, etc)

        // start the initial Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(this, InitialActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

`InitialActivity.class` is indeed an `Activity` that works fine if I set it to be `MAIN`, but trying to start it from `MyApplication` that is declared `MAIN` generates the error. Probably a very silly question, but am I tackling this all wrong?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Do you mean that you're defining MyApplication as an Activity? That would, indeed, cause a ClassCastException.

Happily Android already does for you what you want to do, if I understand correctly what you want to do. You just need to set the name of your application to that path and name of MyApplication. It will be created before your Activities are, and will be available to all of them. Like this: <application android:name="com.yourpath.MyApplicationOn"...

Comment: Interesting - how would I then access custom methods of the application from one of the Activities?

Comment: From within your Activity you can get a handle to the Application thusly: getApplicationContext(), the result of which, if it's configured as above in your manifest, will cast to MyApplication.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can fix this by using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ApplicationActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

That's because you need to start new task when Activity is started outside of Activity context. But I strongly recommend to not start Activity from your Application's `onCreate()`.

---

Android has 4 components: Activity, Service, ContentProvider and Broadcast.

When Android needs to activate one of this components from your application, it looks if there is already existing running process with your application. If not, then Android starts new process, initializes it, then it initializes your custom Application instance. And then it activates one of needed components.

Now, let's consider next scenario: your application declared content provider in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and Android just about to start your application so you can provide some data to another foreground application.

1. Content Provider request is sent
2. Your application wasn't running, and Android starts new process for it.
3. Your custom Application instance is created
4. `Application.onCreate()` is called.
5. You start an activity
6. Your Content Provider receives request

Somebody just wanted to connect to your content provider, but your application started an Activity instead. Same true for starting background Service and sometimes broadcast receivers.

And also consider if some other application's activity A wanted to started activity X from your application. But in `onCreate()` you started activity Y, and then X is also started by Android. Then user presses back. What should happen? Its tricky...

Starting activities from `Application`'s `onCreate` may result in quite weird user experience. So don't do it.

---

**UPDATE:**
Because Android guarantees that Application will be created only once and before any other component, you can use next code to access your Application's single instance:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{   
    private static MyApplication s_instance;

    public MyApplication()
    {
        s_instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getApplication()
    {
        return s_instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. So in terms of declaring custom methods in MyApplication that I can expose to the rest of the `Activity`, is this possible? How would I access them (`getApplication()` doesn't seem to do the trick)

Comment: So any methods that I have in MyApplication that I want to access would be accessed via MyApplication.getApplication().myMethod()?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set it in you manifest activity tag for this intent you are starting (another one besides your main) ?

```
 </activity>
             <activity android:name=".InitialActivity"                          
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.package.INITACT" />  <--- this is only name by which you activity can be called.
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```